How to save decryption key in Python using sqlite during GUI lifespan?
I'm using from pysqlcipher3 import dbapi2 to work with encrypted SQLite databases in a Python application with a GUI. Every time I connect to the database and decrypt it, I use the following code:
    conexion = sqlite3.connect(PATH)
    conexion.execute("PRAGMA key = 'KEY'")
    cursor = conexion.cursor()

However, this process makes my GUI slow. I would like to know if there is a way to cache the decryption key so that the program does not experience slowdowns during CRUD operations.
Here are some specific points where I need help:

Is there a way to persist the decryption key in memory so that it does not need to be re-applied with each database operation?
Are there any best practices for handling encryption keys efficiently in a Python application with a GUI?


Is this a Flask server? Can't you make the connection once when the server starts up, and put it in a global variable?

Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to have two questions here; please split them up into separate questions. Also, thanks for adding code! But each sample should be a [mre], which requires more than you've provided here.
